# How to access the QObject of a Qt UI from another QT application?

Tags: qt

I am intending to implement a simple test QT application in linux which launch a QT UI application running on an Embedded linux platform to verify it. I want to be able to send signals from the test application to the UI, for instance to press a button on the GUI, then check if the signal has made the expected change on the QT UI application. I know there are some tools like Squish, Testability Driver that can hook a running QT application and access the properties of each graphical element (e.g. button).
I have searched a lot, but I could not find any suitable solution. If somebody can introduce a suitable solution?

Comment: I don't realize why you are going to send a signal from one qt application to another one. Are you looking for a way to communicate between the two applications?

Comment: I’d suggest Squish for testing, for monitoring/debugging have a look at gammaray: http://www.kdab.com/kdab-products/gammaray/

Answer (score 1):

On Unix platforms you can use [dbus](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdbus/qtdbus-index.html). Otherwise you have to roll your own mechanism, or use a third party tool.